# Mysql: How to make and read a joined query?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables - one with *articles*, and one with article *related photos*. Each article can have none, one or multiple photos related to it (article_id as foreign key)

Query I use to fetch data is:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, articles.article_text article_photos.photo_filename
FROM articles, article_photos
WHERE article_photos.article_id = articles.article_id
```

And it returns to me all data + 1 photo_filename.

Question is, when 2 or more photos are related to article, how do I read them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will replicate the same row from `articles`, but different row from `article_photos`

such as

```
select articles.article_id, articles.article_text, article_photos.photo_filename
from
  articles
left join article_photos
on article_photos.article_id=articles.article_id

>>> results
1,some_text,photo1.jpg
1,some_text,photo2.jpg
1,some_text,photo3.jpg
2,some_text2,NULL       --> no photo related
```

Comment: Note that the OP's query will return three joined records for article 1, just like this (which is technically what he asked for).  The left join added here points out what the original query would miss: an article with no photos (which the OP may have overlooked).

Comment: @keithjgrant:    does this means my version of query would just skip articles with no photos related?

Comment: @keithjgrant - Yup, is the naturally of inner join (exclude null) `if there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that have no counterpart in another table`

Comment: Thanks guys, this was great! Is there any way I can modify this query so that when there's multiple photos, result for all other fields will be NULL   i.e.  photo 1:     1,some_text,photo1.jpg       NULL,NULL, photo2.jpg       these joins are not easy to grasp, and your help is really valuable, thanks again

Comment: use `group_concat(article_photos.photo_filename) ... group by articles.article_id`

Comment: ajreal, thanks - but I must be doing something wrong, I get the: #1630 - FUNCTION mydatabasename.GROUP_CONCAT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual - is this issue of my mysql config, or is it syntax? how should I exactly add this to a query?

Comment: post your full query into a new question?

Comment: I tried a few approaches with different errors, and finally posted a question with your (working) query as starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740598/how-to-add-group-concat-to-left-join-query

Comment: edit: after a bit more work I got it where I wanted it, so thanks once again...these queries are not easy to grasp but seems practice helps a lot