# How to add GROUP_CONCAT to LEFT JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, group-concat

I have this query (and results):

```
select articles.article_id, articles.article_text, article_photos.photo_filename
from
  articles
left join article_photos
on article_photos.article_id=articles.article_id

>>> results
1,some_text,photo1.jpg
1,some_text,photo2.jpg
1,some_text,photo3.jpg
```

How do I incorporate GROUP_CONCAT to this so that I get:

```
>>> results

1,some_text,photo1.jpg
NULL,NULL,photo2.jpg
NULL,NULL,photo3.jpg
```

Basically, I have a table with articles, and related table with images. An article can have multiple images belonging to it, so I'm trying to print it on screen within while loop, and don't want text to repeat over and over when there's multiple images.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of the `#1630 - FUNCTION mydatabasename.GROUP_CONCAT does not exist` problem? I'm getting the exact same result and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
select articles.article_id, articles.article_text, group_concat(article_photos.photo_filename)
    from articles
        left join article_photos
            on article_photos.article_id=articles.article_id
    group by articles.article_id, articles.article_text
```

would return

```
1    some_text    photo1.jpg,photo2.jpg,photo3.jpg
```

which is not quite what you've shown in your expected results. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Hm, this query works, but to me it returns the same result as original query.

Comment: What I have is php looping through these results and printing text on screen, and belonging images below. So, when article has say 3 images related to it, my original query would cause that the same content is also printed 3 times.